# Can't set image int into webview?

Tags: android, webview

Allright so here's my problem. I have an app which contains alot of pictures and i wanted to be able to pinchzoom these, but since the ImageViewer doesnt support this natively I thought I'd use the Webviewer instead, but heres the thing. all my pictures are saved into my "picture" int and its the picture function i want to load into the webviewer. not a specific \drawable\bla.jpg Searched all around but didnt find anything about it. I'll attach some code for reference.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent=getIntent();
int picture=intent.getIntExtra("picture", 22);
setContentView(R.layout.pictureframe);        
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pansarvagn);
image.setBackgroundResource(picture);
```

and its here where i want smth like

```
Webview image = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pansarvagn);
image.(setdata bla bla)
```

and this is the picture function

```
public void displayPicture(int pictureresource){
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("picture", pictureresource);
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Picture.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

called by

```
Button tank = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tank);
tank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
 displayPicture(R.drawable.tank);
}
```

To further elaborate i want to put an image into a webview which i will be able to zoom into. so some sort of imageview inside the webview to fill up the webview with my picture. and then I want to be able to zoom in on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create you own [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.htmlhttp://) and override it's [`opeenFile(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Then you can feed it to WebView:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("content://your.content.provider/someImageName");
```

Here is an example: http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/

Note: with this approach you will need to save your images somewhere. You will not be able to serve them from memory.